# Generalized additive model

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I need help on how to interpret results for Generalised Additive Models(GAM) in R using the mgcv package. I have a dataset  called  flood which has a dependent variable called year (1985-2014) and the predictor variable  called deaths ( number of deaths from flood in each corresponding year) and is binary. If there was no death from a flood it is represented as 0 while if there was any death despite the number, it is represented as 1. I want to check whether the relationship between the two variables is linear or not. Here is the code.

```
    flood$deaths[flood$deaths==0]<-0
    flood$deaths[flood$deaths>0]<-1
    attach(flood)         
    library(mgcv) he relationship
    gam1 = gam(deaths~s(year),family=binomial,data=flood)
    summary(gam1)
```

and the results :

```
    Family: binomial 
    Link function: logit 

    Formula:
    deaths ~ s(year)

    Parametric coefficients:
    a                                     Estimate Std. Error z value      P   pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)  0.98706    0.03791   26.04   <2e-16 ***
              ---
    Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

    Approximate significance of smooth terms:
    edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value
    s(year) 3.886  4.804  7.892   0.131

    R-sq.(adj) =  0.00188   Deviance explained = 0.252%
    UBRE = 0.17011  Scale est. = 1         n = 3527
```

how do i interpret the above results?

Comment: First things first: Why do you reduce the available information, i.e., why do you transform the variable into a binary outcome? It seems preferable to use a Poisson GAM. Why are you interested in knowing if the relationship is nonlinear on the logit scale?

Comment: Thanks Roland. This dataset is part of a larger dataset which has predictor variables such as percentage of forest area, percentage of agricultural land etc. I wanted to check whether these variables are assiociated  with a death  from floods but not the actual amount of deaths. The hypothesis is that the deaths were high in the early years (1985-2000) but now with interventions the deaths have decreased (2000 -2014). Using the GLM would not show this trend thats why i opted for GAM though i am not familiar in that territory.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be more informative to plot predictions with a confidence band than looking at the summary output (which nevertheless tells you that the fit is not excellent)?

Comment: If the relationship were linear, your s(year) would have 1 degree of freedom, but mgcv puts it at 3.886. You can also use plot(gam1) to see the estimated spline and verify that it is not linear. I agree with Roland, though, that this seems like a very indirect test for your hypothesis. You should just test for whats you would like to know, so just drop the GAM and test whether there were significantly more deaths in 85-2000 than in 2000-2014.